# Chrome extension manifest v3; Is there a way to communicate between background service_worker and content_scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, irc, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, twitch-api

I have `service_worker` at background that is running `WebSocket` connection with twitch chat. Also I have `content_script` that is connected to music service api, handling events of current track change. And I need to extract data from `content_script` (current track info) and use it inside `service_worker` script when `WebSocket` receiving message with data request.

Is there any chance to do my task with minimal usage of different manifest permissions?

Important: manifest v3 required

I know that I can use `chrome.scripting.executeScript` to inject utility script that is able to handle `chrome.runtime.onMessage` from background and let my `content_script` serving api know about data request with `window.dispatchEvent` but I dont want to use `permissions: ["scripting"]` and I can't just directly use `chrome.runtime.onMessage` because `chrome` context does not exist at `content_script` that is set by manifest properties.

Also I could run my `WebSocket` at `content_script` but it refuses connection with error `my_content_script_name.js:37 Refused to connect to 'wss://irc-ws.chat.twitch.tv:413/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: [...]` and I can't do anything with that through manifest rule `content_security_policy` because Chrome fires error  `'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value`

Comment: Simply use messaging with scripting. 1) `scripting` doesn't add any permission warnings so you can safely use it. 2) If `chrome` doesn't exist in a content script for you it means you've explicitly specified the unsafe `"world": "MAIN"`, which you shouldn't generally do, so just remove it. If you really need it then you'll have to use a second content script in default world which can communicate via `chrome`, these two scripts can communicate via CustomEvent. 3) Indeed content scripts can't receive data from a cross-origin URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for your guidance, your second tip works perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @wOxxOm comment (thanks), need to use two `content_scripts`:

- first one (without specified `"world"` property) to run `WebSocket`;
- second one in `"world": "MAIN"` to work with page api;

To communicate between them we can use `CustomEvent`, `window.dispatchEvent` and `window.addEventListener`. So for now when script #1 with `WebSocket` receiving specific command message I can dispatch event requesting data from script #2.